# Redirecting current Unity API Reference to Unity 4.x

Tags: unity-game-engine, monodevelop

Is there any way to use the Unity **4.x** API Reference when pressing <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd> in MonoDevelop? It currently references the 2017 API.

I've tried using Redirect, but the paths were a bit confusing to understand.

Comment: maybe you should update ;)

Comment: I definitely would, but I'm taking a course where this version of Unity is required. Also, i have a 32-bit system, which the 2017 version doesn't support.